# javascript how to store url with param in object

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, request

I want to store url with param in object like this:

```
var list = [
  {
    name: 'Hello world',
    url: 'http://www.thisismyurl.com/' + latlon + '/endofmyurl'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hello world2',
    url: 'http://www.thisismyurl2.com/' + latlon + '/endofmyurl'
  },
   ...
];
```

So then when I want to make a request I can use the url and change the variable latlon by the real latlon. But at the start my latlon doesn't exist yet so I got an error.

> Cannot read property 'latlon' of undefined

I have a lot of parameters in the url so I don't know how to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if latlon doesn't exist yet, then you can call that code block when it does exist and that should solve your problem. The easiest way to do that would be to wrap it in a function like this:

```js
var getList = function (latlon) {
  return [
    {
      name: 'Hello world',
      url: 'http://www.thisismyurl.com/' + latlon + '/endofmyurl'
    },
    {
      name: 'Hello world2',
      url: 'http://www.thisismyurl2.com/' + latlon + '/endofmyurl'
    }
  ];
}

var latlon = "hereismystring";
getList(latlon);
```

Comment: My answer is assuming that you would be updating the "latlon" variable and possibly make multiple requests. If not, then Jaspers answer above would be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just define latlon before.

```
var latlon = 'lat/27.664827/lon/-81.515754';

var list = [
{
  name: 'Hello world',
  url: 'http://www.thisismyurl.com/' + latlon + '/endofmyurl'
},
{
  name: 'Hello world2',
  url: 'http://www.thisismyurl2.com/' + latlon + '/endofmyurl'
},
...
];
```

Comment: I can't cos it will be different every time I use the url

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
var list = Array();  

function addObj(name, url, latlon){
    list.push({
        name: name,
        url: url[0] + latlon + url[1]
    })
}

addObj('Hello world', ['http://www.thisismyurl.com/', '/endofmyurl'], '27.664827-81.515754');
```